Move contents of Git branch to another branch in same repository
I want to move the entire contents of a GIt branch (main) to another branch in the same repository (development), leaving the first branch (main) empty. I have read many posts but none of them give me confidence that I understand what will happen and how to do this.

This is certainly an atypical use of git’s branching feature; can you provide just a bit of detail as to what is compelling you to this course of action? This smells a lot like an XY problem, but there’s not enough information here to be certain.

Draw the history you have, draw the history you want. Make the new commits, re-hang the labels where you want them, done.

@esqew I have never heard of XY problem. I have a new repository with only the main branch with some contents. I want to treat the main branch as a public deployment branch which will initially have no content. I want to create a Development branch which will be the internal organization deployment branch, Anything in Development has been or will be deployed internally, New development and maintenance will be perfored on topic branches branched from development. I am trying to populate this structure.

@jthill I have limited experience with Git and I do not know how to translate your suggestions into Git commands.

If you've only got the one branch history should be a straight line, each commit to its only parent. That seems to be what you're describing, is that correct?

@jthill That is correct.

@jthill In addition, everything only has one commit each as this is a new repository.

Git is an arbitrarily-extensible dag of immutable snapshots, with re-hangable labels. That's not an abstraction, that's what it is. You have a linear series of complete snapshots, every commit is self-contained and refers to any immediate ancestors(s). However you want to refer to your existing history, give it a new name with git branch thatname. If you deployment branch should start farther back, at some commit in existing history, git branch deployment $thatcommit to hang the deployment-branch label on that commit.

Stop thinking of a branch as a collection of commits.  Think of the git repository as a directed graph of immutable commits.  The branch is just a label to one of those commits.  A single commit can have many labels attached to it.  The label can be moved to other commits.  Humans tend to think of the branch as the commit it is currently attached to and all its ancestors (which is fine) but seem to continue to associate those commits with the branch even after the branch has been moved to refer to a completely unrelated set of commits (which is bad).

There is no such thing as "contents of a branch" or "entire contents of a branch". A branch is merely a string; it's a label for one commit. And that's basically all it is.
If you don't like the name that a certain commit has, give it another name!
git switch main
git switch -C development
git branch -D main

That forcibly moves the name "development" to the commit where the name "main" is now, and throws the name "main" away. Any commit previously pointed to by the name "development" presumably now would have no name pointing to it; that commit is now unreachable, and it and any of its ancestors that are also unreachable will eventually be garbage-collected and deleted.
